# Which Normal distribution a point belongs to?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, gaussian

I have estimated normal distributions for two classes (0 and 1). The distributions for the two classes are,

\begin{align}
X_0 &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu=549.96,~~ \sigma=549.96) \\
X_1 &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu=250.047, \sigma=8.33)
\end{align}

Now, I am given a sample, say $ x = 381.82 $, and I need to tell if it is more probable to belong to class 0 or it is more probable to belong to class 1.

What do I do? Calculate normal `cdf`? Or do I need to calculate density at the given point? I am using `matlab` for implementation but it does not matter because we are not allowed to use any builtin functions.
Regards
Adeel

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test or, if you're feeling adventurous, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor

Comment: Why so many down votes? Only problems I see here are minor formatting issues and that this might be better in https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this looks more a statistics homework exercise (without any effort from OP), than a data science question to me.

Comment: On the 'not allowed to use any built-in functions': homework? From a philosophic point of view, even adding is a build in function.

Comment: Down voters should at least comment. I did not ask for any solution or code. Its just that I can't tell if a point is more likely to belong to one distribution or the other. I can do the implementation.

Comment: Also I got this question in Machine Learning assignment and the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ I posted are estimated from data. That's why I put the question on this forum rather than stats

Answer (score 2):

A common distance measure between a point and a normal distribution is the number of standard deviations away from the mean.

In your case:

$$d_0 = |x-μ_0|/σ_0 = 15.4$$

$$d_1 = |x-μ_1|/σ_1 = 15.82$$

See [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) for generalization in multiple dimensions.

Comment: The problem is that this is not probability.

Comment: @SmallChess The probability of any point being sampled from a continuous distribution is zero without a width $ \Delta x $ being specified. But you are correct that this could be slightly modified to give a probability ratio and that would better answer the question.

Comment: I agree with this. Particularly since we assume normality, saying how many standard deviations a point is from the mean tells us how mainstream that value is for a distribution. The point is more likely to have come from the distribution where it would be a more mainstream value, though that can break down upon dropping the normality assumption.